# How to do az acr import with Az powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli

If Az powershell does not have it, then a working code sample using the [REST Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/containerregistry/registries/importimage#code-try-0) would be helpful.

This is the path I am going to pursue, but if someone has a working sample - please share.

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot find it in Azure PowerShell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to trigger the import using REST API. Here is my code (using a Service Principal to login):

```
function Get-AcrId($SubId, $RGName, $AcrName)
{
    "/subscriptions/$SubId/resourceGroups/$RGName/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/$ACRName"
}

function Get-AzureAuthenticationToken(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)][String]$TenantID,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)][String]$ClientID,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)][String]$ClientSecret,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)][String]$ResourceAppIDUri)
{
    $tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -UseBasicParsing `
        -Uri "https://login.windows.net/$TenantID/oauth2/token" `
        -Body @{
        resource      = $ResourceAppIDUri
        client_id     = $ClientID
        grant_type    = 'client_credentials'
        client_secret = $ClientSecret
    } -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

    Write-Verbose "Access token type is $($tokenResponse.token_type), expires $($tokenResponse.expires_on)"
    $tokenResponse.access_token
}

function Import-DockerImage(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]$SourceSubId,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]$SourceRGName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]$SourceACRName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]$TargetSubId,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]$TargetRGName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]$TargetACRName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]$ImageName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]$ImageTag
)
{
    $AzContext = Get-AzContext
    if (!$AzContext)
    {
        throw "No Az context is found."
    }
    $TenantId = $AzContext.Tenant.Id
    $ClientId = $AzContext.Account.Id
    $ClientSecret = $AzContext.Account.ExtendedProperties.ServicePrincipalSecret
    $token = Get-AzureAuthenticationToken -TenantID $TenantId -ClientID $ClientId -ClientSecret $ClientSecret -ResourceAppIDUri "https://management.core.windows.net/"

    $url = "https://management.azure.com$(Get-AcrId $TargetSubId $TargetRGName $TargetACRName)/importImage?api-version=2019-05-01"
    $body = @{
        source     = @{
            resourceId  = Get-AcrId $SourceSubId $SourceRGName $SourceACRName
            sourceImage = "${ImageName}:$ImageTag"
        }
        targetTags = @(
            "${ImageName}:$ImageTag"
        )
        mode       = "NoForce"
    } | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99
    $headers = @{
        "Authorization" = "Bearer $token"
        "Content-Type"  = "application/json" 
    }
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
    $r = Invoke-WebRequest $url -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $body

    $headers.Remove('Content-Type')
    while ($r.StatusCode -eq 202)
    {
        $RetryAfter = $r.Headers.'Retry-After'
        $Location = $r.Headers.Location
        Start-Sleep -Seconds $RetryAfter
        $r = Invoke-WebRequest $Location -Headers $headers
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to import images to ACR through the Azure PowerShell, but the REST API exists. Take a look at the [Import Image REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/containerregistry/registries/importimage).

Comment: I am doing exactly it. So far unsuccessful. I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: @mark So what about the answer you add? Is that the situation or the solution according to mine?

Comment: It uses the Import REST API as both of us have thought. But devil is in details, I provided the details for those who need to repeat the effort.

Comment: @mark I cannot see any requirement that you ask in the question for the details, no Java, no Python, just nothing.

Comment: my bad I should have indicated more clearly that I am looking for the details, because it is obviously possible to do, given that Azure CLI does it. So details are important. I will make sure to be more precise the next time.